# Conversion error between "DT_DBTIME2" and "DT_WSTR" for "ETAHour"

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a SQL query that returns me a `"time(0)"`. I load that into SSIS, and it gets automatically converted to a `"DT_DBTIME2"`, which is okay. I can transform it to any other type without error using a data conversion data flow item.

My problem is that when I try to insert that value into a `"time(0)"` field of a table, it gives me the following error:

> The OLE DB provider used by the OLE DB adapter cannot convert between
>   types "DT_DBTIME2" and "DT_WSTR" for "ETAHour".

When I mouse over the fields in the `OLE DB` Destination component, it clearly says that the source field is a `DT_DBTIME2` and the destination field is a `DT_DBTIME2`. I really wonder where this conversion error comes from.

Comment: I have no idea what a time(0) is. What's the source & destination RDBMS?

Comment: MSSQL 2008. time(0) will result in HH:MM:SS with 0 precision on milliseconds.

Comment: I know it was long time ago, but I'm experiencing same problem. Works on my local machine, but doesn't on test server. We are using MSSQL 2012 Enterprise...

Comment: Found problem, see my answer bellow. Probably you have sorted this out somehow looong time ago, but I think it would be good to share definite answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are specifying provider in connection string.

In my case I'm using MSSQL 2012 Enterprise. It works on local machine, but after updating connection string in dtsconfig in installer it fails with error above.

Setting OLE DB provider fixed issue, in my case:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue after importing an existing SSIS project created a new connection string and after I switched had multiple errors.

Changing the OLE DB provider to SQL Server Native Client 11.0 solved issue which is the equivalent of setting SQLNCLI11.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syfro.png)